# Замена одной из двух больших букв подряд

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо определить, есть ли в слове две или три идущие подряд заглавные буквы и, если они есть, то удалить, оставив последнюю из двух или трех заглавных букв:

```
МММорковь и ГГруша    =>    Морковь и Груша
```

Заглавные буквы могут быть только в начале слова. Только кириллица, аббревиатур в тексте не будет.

Comment: Только кириллица? А если аббревиатура?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Только кириллица, аббревиатур в тексте не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Не смотря на уточнение про аббревиатуры, хотелось всё же какой-то универсальности.

```
/([^\w]|^)([А-ЯЁ])+(\2(?=[а-яё]))/gm    =>    $1$2
```

Регулярные выражения в JS имеют некоторые ограничения (например, *lookbehind*), поэтому выглядят иногда запутанно и громоздко. Ждём, когда дополнят, а пока выкручиваемся, как можем:

```js
let sTxt = `ППревратить МММорковь в Морковь. Из слова ГГруша, сделать слово Груша.
Ни ООО "РогаИКопыта" ни новая райДЕЗ не следуют требованиям СНиП и КЗоТ.
Во времена СССР, ЦПКиО Санкт-ППетербурга присваивается имя С. М. КККККирова.
МВ-печь и МТ-ЛБ - техника.`;

let rExp = /([^\w]|^)([А-ЯЁ])+(\2(?=[а-яё]))/gm;

console.error(sTxt); // Исходный текст
console.info(sTxt.replace(rExp, '$1$2'));
```